# Getting a specific var of <class 'web3.datastructures.AttributeDict'>

Tags: web3.py, python, calldata

I have this code that is printing out all the vars of the class; however, I am only interested in the "input" var. Is there an easy way to access this this "'input': '0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000e428127cc2055e5c9d756ddce356aa2bf8da379b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015ba31f54770ec000'

```
from pprint import pprint
from textwrap import indent
from web3 import Web3

bsc = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"  # for ETH use Infura
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(bsc))
print("Connected to web3: ", w3.isConnected())
# ----------------------------------

# enter tx_hash 0x24cc5476a1c96fb9ebe2daf63a970643195532682843aed692249033b1844440
tx_hash = "0x24cc5476a1c96fb9ebe2daf63a970643195532682843aed692249033b1844440"

# raw_data = w3.eth.get_raw_transaction(tx_hash)
# print("\n\n", raw_data.hex())

data = w3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash)
pprint(vars(data))
```

below is my output

```
  {'blockHash': 
  HexBytes('0x4146c9f1f78c8e37f778723ef0365cdedb96c06d8b0956bc04d0c2e4087541e0'),
 'blockNumber': 10707576,
 'from': '0x2CfF6fB5a463735D65c29d933CE7f1C45350cb33',
 'gas': 66177,
 'gasPrice': 5000000000,
 'hash': HexBytes('0x24cc5476a1c96fb9ebe2daf63a970643195532682843aed692249033b1844440'),
 'input': '0x095ea7b3000000000000000000000000e428127cc2055e5c9d756ddce356aa2bf8da379b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015ba31f54770ec000',
 'nonce': 2064,
 'r': HexBytes('0x695d48b9b33402a922b9e33febaf637aa9105c4bf18e57a7d6ced489d9c9588d'),
 's': HexBytes('0x16d481ca432653ed29283e8e21f86eb4c5d359cc7553b037e2c62e3b0ef43c6c'),
 'to': '0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56',
 'transactionIndex': 134,
 'type': '0x0',
 'v': 148,
 'value': 0}
```

Comment: This is my solution for now but there must be a better way:       <code> data = w3.eth.get_transaction(tx_hash)

string_out = dict(vars(data))

tx_data = string_out.get("input")
print(tx_data)<\code>

Answer (score 1):

```
print(vars(data)['input'])
```

It's a dictionary:

```
>>> type(vars(data))
<class 'dict'>
```

[image]